# Parbolic Equation using 3 points

Tags: java, math, graphics

Alright so I need to make a parabola that stretches across the length of my World. (W)
I am creating this in a world where the top left corner is (0,0)

my 3 points are from left to right, (x,y)

(0,H)
(W/2,0) << vertex
(W,H)

This would be from the bottom left corner of the world, to the vertex in the top center of the world, to the bottom right corner of the world.

I am sure I made this so much more complicated then it needed to be, but I fried my brain attempting to figure it out.

Also the way this would work is I would want a graphic to travel the parabola over a given amount of time.

so I would make a function to get the Y, and I would send it the X which would range from 0 to W, depending on the time elapsed.

so i would call the function,

```
     GetPathY((WorldWidth*Percentage));
private int getPathY(double X) {
    int y = (int) ScreenHeight-((4 * ScreenHeight* X)/(WorldWidth^2))
    return(y);
}
```

would this work i think?

So: y=(((-4*ScreenHeight)/(WorldWidth^2))(x-(WorldWidth/2)^2)) or: y = H-((4Hx)/(W^2));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made a second way to do it.

1st way I got by rearranging y=a(x-h)^2+k, to solve for 'a'

```
    y=(WindowHeight/((WindowWidth/2)^2)*(x-(WindowWidth/2))^2
```

2nd way, just make two percentiles, one for up, one for horizontal. As time goes scale the X-axis percentile from 0-100% and Y-axis from 0-100% halfway into the time and then back down from 100-0% all you had to do is for the Y-axis add in a modifier so that it starts fast and slows down as it reached 100%. This will provide the curve.

Of course, the equation is easier :)

I would appreciate if you did not delete this post, because My answer was fundamentally different then the other guys, and both my solutions are valid and also different. I used nothing of his answer to obtain my own, and both these solutions may help someone else who is attempting to solve something similar in the future. Also in the reason that the first answer did not help to solve the problem in the way which it was described.

Answer (score 4):

What's the equation for a parabola?

```
y(x) = c0 + c1*x + c2*x^2
```

You have three points:

```
y(0) = c0 = H
```

And another:

```
y(W/2) = H + c1*(W/2) + c2*(W/2)^2 = 0
```

You can solve this for either c1 or c2.  Let's do it for c2:

```
c2 = -4H/W^2 - 2c1/W
```

Then there's the last equation:

```
y(W) = H + c1*(W) + c2*(W^2) = H
```

Subtract H from both sides gives:

```
c1*W + c2*W^2 = = 0
```

Simplify this one to get c1:

```
c1 = -c2*W
```

Substitute the coefficient that you solved for in the second equation into this one to get the third and you're done.

It's just algebra.

Comment: So:

y=(((-4*ScreenHeight)/(WorldWidth^2))(x-(WorldWidth/2)^2))

or:
y = H-((4Hx)/(W^2))

Comment: Is that what applying these steps got you?  Then yes, that's it.  Check yourself with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Except this didnt get me what I needed, it only made me more confused. What got me what I needed was rearranging the equation y=a(x-h)+k, which is what I was trying to do in the first place, what ever you did was just more complicated.

Comment: Whatever.  It's not my fault that you're math challenged.  This is high school algebra, nothing more.